# How to solve the problem parseXML with DataTables and Excel?

Tags: javascript, symfony, datatable, datatables

I have a problem with DataTables and Excel. I use pdf and print function, it works well but Excel not. I have this message in the browser (with F12):

```
> Uncaught TypeError: f.parseXML is not a function
    at a (buttons.html5.min.js:26)
    at _Api.action (buttons.html5.min.js:26)
    at v (dataTables.buttons.min.js:16)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (dataTables.buttons.min.js:17)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.v.handle (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
```

My javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

            var table = $('#summary').DataTable({
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: ['excel', 'csv', 'pdf', 'print']});

            });

    </script>
```

My base.html.twig

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/flatly/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.4/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.4/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.7/css/select.dataTables.min.css">       
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://editor.datatables.net/extensions/Editor/css/editor.dataTables.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/main.css') }}" />
    {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}   
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>  
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>   
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.4/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.4/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.4/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.4/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.7/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>   
    <script src="https://editor.datatables.net/extensions/Editor/js/dataTables.editor.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://editor.datatables.net/extensions/Editor/js/editor.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/sorting/datetime-moment.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/dataRender/datetime.js"></script>

    <div class="container">
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
</div>
{% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

The button appears but it doesn't work. I'm working with Chrome. I searched but I did not find the solution.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 10):

You are using the slim version of jQuery which does not support the parseXML function. Use the normal version instead. For version 3.3.1 it will be:

```
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

For all current versions go to https://code.jquery.com/jquery/ and choose the "minified" version of jQuery Core (and NOT the "slim minified" version).